# jQuery.key returns Unindentified Android keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, keyboard

I'm trying to make my phone number input field to be numerical only (0-9). I'm using jQuery key to make this possible with this code.

```
$("#phonenumber").keydown(function (e) {
   if (!(e.key.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "") === "" && e.key != "Backspace" && e.key != "Delete")) {
     //I added Backspace and Delete so I can use those keys.
     return;
   } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
   }
});
```

This is working with Computer and iPhone devices. However in Android devices, it can only deflect the alphabets and some special character **BUT** some of it can go through! I tried to **alert()** the **e.key** and it returns **Unidentified** when I tried to type with a special character. I tried to add it on my **if condition** however **e.preventDefault()** and **return false** isn't working. And when I tried to **$('#phonenumber').val()** it is blank but there's a special character like this.

[image]

The **e.key != "Backspace" && e.key != "Delete"** only working with Windows and iPhone. The android returns backspace as **Unidentified** too.

How can I resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to find key code in your event

```
let key_code = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
```

and you can see list of keycode in this link:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/#article-header-id-1

Comment: Hi, but this only returns **Unidentified** key to 0.

Comment: Try keyUp instead of keyDown